# How to add rotated underlined message on top of the div

Tags: html, css

I need to create a box which has a rotated message on top with `border-bottom`, however I can't make it responsive. The bottom line should always go from border to border.

```css
.holder {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
}
.rotated-text {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);

}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="rotated-text">
    <p>Hello! <br> This text is rotated</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use `position: absolute` or some `clip-path` but it didn't work out. Is should look something like this:

[image]

If it is not possible I guess I will have to use an image. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sample here. In this one the width and and height of rotated-text div is fixed. But it can stick to top right corner of its container always.

```css
.holder {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  position:relative
}
.rotated-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 65px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  right:7px;
  top: 26px;
  background: red;
}
.rotated-text p{
  margin:0;
}
.rotated-text:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -64px;
  right:-63px;
  bottom:0;
  height: 1px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="rotated-text">
    <p>Hello! <br> This text is rotated</p>
  </div>
</div>
```